# angular formControl validation

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add validations to mat-select where the user needs to select at least one entry

html file:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select drink(s):</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="drinks" multiple (selectionChange)="checkSelectedDrinks($event.value)">
    @for (drink of drinkList; track drink) {
    <mat-option [value]="drink">{{drink}}</mat-option>
    }
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="drinkSelectionErr">
    You need to select at least one drink
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts file:

```
drinkList: string[] = ["A","B","C","D","E"];

drinks = new FormControl(this.drinkList);

  checkSelectedDrinks(selectedDrinks: string[]){
    if (!selectedDrinks.length){
      this.drinkSelectionErr = true;
    }
  }
```

The code above does nothing when all drinks are unselected from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 4):

You are not [setting any validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation). Remove the `onchange` and add a validator.

```
drinks = new FormControl(this.drinkList, Validators.required);
```

Then the control will be marked invalid when nothing is selected and you can display it in the HTML.

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="drinks.errors?.required">
    You need to select at least one drink
  </mat-error>
```

Note that your validator could return multiple errors, in which case, you'd need to switch between possible error codes (`must.select.item`) to display the correct error message.

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="drinks.errors?.otherMessage">
    Another type of error.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example for your reference, we can just use the `required` validator of angular!

1. We need to prefer using [`Reactive Forms`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) since its a logical grouping of form controls, which allow as to apply actions/get data from multiple controls at once.
2. When you initialize a form Control, we have a second argument which accepts an array of [`validators`](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators) in our particular scenario, we need a value to be present so we need to use `required` validator.
3. After that, when no value is present, we get a property called `required` in the `errors` property of the control. We can access the value by using `form?.controls?.drinks?.errors?.required`, The question mark is for typescript to convert into automatic null checking `form && form.controls && form.controls.drinks and so on...`

So by combining all these concepts we can achieve the desired result!

Do read up on the reactive forms documentation, all the best!

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

/**
 * @title Basic Inputs
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['input-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
})
export class InputOverviewExample {
  drink = 'test';
  drinkList = ['test', 'test2', 'test3'];
  form = new FormGroup({
    drinks: new FormControl([this.drink], [Validators.required]),
  });
}
```

html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select drink(s):</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="drinks" multiple>
      @for (drink of drinkList; track drink) {
      <mat-option [value]="drink">{{drink}}</mat-option>
      }
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form?.controls?.drinks?.errors?.required">
      You need to select at least one drink
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ia8xda?file=src%2Fexample%2Finput-overview-example.css,src%2Fexample%2Finput-overview-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Finput-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Nice and concise. An improvement over my [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77832733/227299), I wasn't sure if `required` would work for `mat-select` and was too lazy too write a Stackblitz.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution:

For mat-error, I updated the 'if' condition  to use the fromControl status attribute

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="drinks['status'] === 'INVALID'">
    You need to select at least one drink
  </mat-error>
```

Comment: `drinks.invalid` is the correct way. Your answer still doesn't show that you're setting any validators on your `FormControl`.

Comment: @RuanMendes, yes `drinks.invalid` works. Besides, `drinks.status == 'INVALID'` or `!drinks.valid` are alternatives. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#status

Comment: @YongShun I know but why would you use `drinks.status == 'INVALID'` instead of `valid`/`invalid`? Correct may not have been very accurate, preferred would have worked better. Still, this answer doesn't set a validator, which is my main point.

Comment: A `*ngIf` in a mat-error it's only when there're more that one validator to know the "error". If only one validator we can forget the ugly *ngIf